# Wordpress MultiSite : CONSTANT or variable that focuses on Site

Tags: wordpress

This is a tough one, and will require some up to date expertise on Wordpress to figure this one out.

I have an external script that hooks into the database backend and I can work with everything pretty successfully, but one thing I cannot do is get permalinks using get_permalink($post_id) for any blog other than the main blog.

For example, if I switch my table prefix from wp_1_ to wp_2_ so that my focus is on workin with blog id 2, get_permalink() when called will still try to get the permalink for blog 1, because I am including /wp-config.php.

What/how can I change a CONSTANT so that get_permalink() will pull from a newly designated blog id?

I really appreciate any guidance,

Hudson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `switch_to_blog($blog_ID)` - [codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/switch_to_blog](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/switch_to_blog).

WordPress is then aware of which blog you're working with, and all functions should work as expected.